# Ghost Blog posts sort order

Tags: ghost-blog

Has anyone figured out a simple/quick way to use a custom post sort order with Ghost?

Specifically I would like to implement a theme that uses Ghost's tag-{slug}.hbs functionality to render tag specific pages that order posts oldest>newest instead of the default newest>oldest.

Any ideas vs. hacking at ghost core and making a big mess?

Thanks

Comment: Currently, it isn't possible: https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/issues/889

Answer (score 2):

You can not make the blog engine return a different sort order. But what you can do is use template code to throw away the results provided by the engine and make it fetch new results with the `#get` helper.

```
    {{#has any="tag.feature_image"}}
        {{#get "posts" filter="tags.slug:{{tag.slug}}" limit=100 order="published_at asc"}}
            <!-- `posts` from the parent context is overwritten by get -->
            {> "loop"}}
        {{/get}}
    {{else}}
            <!-- default loop -->
            {{> "loop"}}
    {{/has}}
```

I for example wanted to list posts in tag.hbs in chronological order if the Tag had a `featured_image`. So for such tags I use the `#get` helper to get the posts in chronological order (`order="published_at asc"`). If not the posts already provided by the blogging engine in reverse order are displayed.

Answer (score 1):

See : https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/issues/5602,

To order post oldest > newest, edit the *core\server\models\post.js* file, find the `orderDefaultOptions` function and change the `published_at` value ('ASC') :

```
orderDefaultOptions: function orderDefaultOptions() {
    return {
        status: 'ASC',
        published_at: 'ASC',
        updated_at: 'DESC',
        id: 'DESC'
    };
},
```

Answer (score 0):

add this line

`"postinstall": "sed -i \"s/published_at: 'DESC'/published_at: 'ASC'/g\" node_modules/ghost/core/server/models/post.js && sed -i \"s/_at DESC,'/_at ASC,'/g\" node_modules/ghost/core/server/models/post.js",`

inside `scripts` section in your `package.json` it should work